# Translate custom validationErrorMessages in typo3 forms with locallang.xlf

Tags: forms, validation, typo3, translation, typo3-9.x

I use locallang.xlf to translate my form (typo3 9.5.5, formextension).

my customform.yaml:

```
       renderables:
          -
            properties:
              fluidAdditionalAttributes:
                required: required
              validationErrorMessages:
                -
                  code: 1221560910
                  message: 'My Custom Message'
                  code: 1221560718
                  message: 'My Custom Message'
                -
                  code: 1347992400
                  message: 'My Custom Message'
                -
                  code: 1347992400
                  message: 'My Custom Message'
              options:
                products: 'Products'
                miscellaneous: 'Sonstiges'
              prependOptionLabel: 'Please Specify'
            type: SingleSelect
            identifier: subject
            label: 'Your Subject:'
            validators:
              -
                identifier: NotEmpty
          -
```

my locallang.xlf:

```
        <trans-unit id="element.subject.properties.prependOptionLabel">
            <source>Please Specify --Works!</source>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="element.subject.properties.options.products">
                <source>Products --Works!</source>
        </trans-unit>
    <trans-unit id="element.subject.properties.validationErrorMessages.message">
            <source>Custom Message -Doesn't work!</source>
        </trans-unit>
```

With an exact translation key it works, except validationErrorMessages. 
Does anyone know how to translate these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following translation keys for validation error codes. `1221559976` is the code for the `EmailAddress` validator:

```
<trans-unit id="validation.error.1221559976">
    <source>Please enter valid email address. Thanks!</source>
    <target>Bitte gebe eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse ein. Danke!</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="MyContactForm.validation.error.1221559976">
    <source>Please enter valid email address. Thank you very much!</source>
    <target>Bitte gebe eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse ein. Vielen herzlichen Dank!</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The latter will override the first, as it contains the form identifier and is therefore more specific.

**Keep in mind that both of these translation keys will not work if you already set a custom message in your form definition!**

This means, the last three lines of the following example have to be removed:

```
renderables:
  -
    defaultValue: ''
    identifier: email
    label: Email
    type: Text
    properties:
      fluidAdditionalAttributes:
        placeholder: 'Email address'
      ### Don't set this if you want to translate the message:
      #validationErrorMessages:
      #  - code: 1221559976
      #    message: 'Please enter a valid email address, dear.'
```